# Ado.NET C# Как изменить запись в DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, datatable, ado

Не смогла найти в интернете адекватного объяснения работы с DataTable для изменения записей. Если у кого-то есть ссылки на источники, буду очень благодарна.

Мне нужно при нажатии кнопки проверять, есть ли в DataTable запись в поле Kod_Menu с кодом, который передаётся в Button.Tag . Как это правильно реализовать?

```
        public void Mouse_Click_Menu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button B = (Button)sender;
        SqlConnection conK = Util.ConnectBD.Get_KDB();
        SqlCommand Cena = new SqlCommand("Select Cena from _Menu where Kod_Menu = " + B.Tag, conK);
        SqlCommand Nazv = new SqlCommand("Select Nazv_Menu from _Menu where Kod_Menu = " + B.Tag, conK);
        float cena = Convert.ToSingle(Cena.ExecuteScalar());
        string nazv = Nazv.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        //Проверка на наличие номенклатуры в DataTable

        DataRow[] row = Sostav.Select("*", "Kod_menu=" + B.Tag);//Попытка получить нужную строку, а после запустить цикл foreach
            if (row != null)
            {
                int i = 0;//Переменная, которая должна хранить значение количества из полученной строки
                i = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]["Kol"]);//преобразование
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());//попытка проверить полученное значение
                //Здесь что-то должно быть, но я уже запутался.
                Sostav.Rows.Add(new object[] { kod_z, B.Tag, nazv, i+1, cena });//вместо добавления строки должно быть обновление
            }
        else
        {
            Sostav.Rows.Add(new object[] { kod_z, B.Tag, nazv, 1, cena });
        }
        List_Zalkaz();
    }
```

Были идеи брать значение количества из найденной записи, удалять эту запись, а после добавлять с новым значением.
Помогите пожалуйста, хотя бы каким-нибудь источником, где можно найти информацию об этом. Очень долго смотрю и ищу, ничего не работает.

Comment: В чем у вас проблема? Изменения которые вы провели в DataTable не сохраняются в БД?

Comment: Постоянные ошибки. В интернете я не нашла правильного решения. Грубо говоря, мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку инкрементировать значение количества в соответствующей строке по условию. В интернете пишут и про linq, и про запросы, но linq пока сложно учить, а запросы выдают ошибку Exeption.

Comment: @AB я чуть позже попробую написать вам инструкцию, если еще актуально отпишитесь

Comment: Да, актуально. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым. Я не знаю, как он там сам устанавливает нужную строку в цикле Foreach, главное, что работает. Вот код:

```
    public void Mouse_Click_Menu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button B = (Button)sender;
        SqlConnection conK = Util.ConnectBD.Get_KDB();
        SqlCommand Cena = new SqlCommand("Select Cena from _Menu where Kod_Menu = " + B.Tag, conK);
        SqlCommand Nazv = new SqlCommand("Select Nazv_Menu from _Menu where Kod_Menu = " + B.Tag, conK);
        float cena = Convert.ToSingle(Cena.ExecuteScalar());
        string nazv = Nazv.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        //Проверка на наличие номенклатуры в DataTable

        DataRow[] row = Sostav.Select("Kod_menu=" + B.Tag);//Попытка получить нужную строку, а после запустить цикл foreach
        if (row.Count() == 0)//Проверка полученных строк из выборки row. В данном случае, если запрос не вернул строк, то добавляем в таблицу запись
        {
            Sostav.Rows.Add(new object[] { kod_z, B.Tag, nazv, 1, cena });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var r in row)// я так понимаю, что мы присваиваем элементу r
            {
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(r["Kol"]);
                int c = Convert.ToInt32(r["Cena"]);

                r["Kol"] = i + 1;
                r["Cena"] = c + c/i;

            }
        }
        List_Zalkaz();
    }
```